# Select Start Of Word Document

Tags: vba, ms-word, blueprism

I am using Blueprism to automate a process involving Word. I have code which will select everything in a word document 
I want to select a document and go to the top of the page (like pressing home)
Is it possible to amend my code?

```
Dim d As Object = GetDocument(handle,document_name)

d.Select

d = Nothing
```

Comment: In general, programming with the Selection object is slower and less reliable than using the Range object. Is selecting absolutely necessary?

Comment: I am open to alternatives @JohnKorchok

Comment: Here's how to set a range to the beginning of a document: `Dim oRange as Range Set oRange = ActiveDocument.Content oRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart`